# Login to Drupal 6 website from Chrome Extension

Tags: drupal, authentication, module, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently building a chrome extension that pulls data from a Drupal 6 website, which works without issue. I'd like to also authenticate users that aren't logged in to the website straight from the Chrome Extension by entering their username and password.

I'm not completely experienced with Drupal, so I am not sure what the best way of doing this is:

- I could send my username/password from the Chrome extension to a custom Drupal module that authenticates if there is a a drupal login function I can use? I don't think I can send a cURL POST request straight to the existing login function as Drupal adds unique IDs to forms I believe?

Or

- Is there a pre-existing remote login module I can use for this?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found the Drupal Services module allows me to authenticate users remotely. However, users authenticated via the services module are limited to the session that is created.

For example, If I logged in a user via my Chrome Extension using the above method, I could send subsequent authenticated requests from the chrome extension using a session key, but If I went to the main drupal website, I would not have an authenticated cookie, and thus would still have to log in.

The work around for this was to add user_authenticate() in the services module authentication function.